# Transition to different state with state params

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Hi I am new to angular routing and was wondering how I can transition to different states through controllers.

I know that I must inject the $state service which I did but I am unclear on how to use the transition method for the service.

This is what I have in my controller code to try to transition but it is not working :( (I tried to $stateService.go(...) as well but no success)

```
$stateService.transitionTo("teststate({ path: 'Test.TestState' })");
```

Here is my state definition

```
    $stateProvider
        .state("teststate",
        {
            url: '/:path',
            templateUrl: (stateParams) => {
                return '/Templates?path=' + stateParams.path;
            },
        })
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
$state.go("teststate", { path: 'Test.TestState' });
```

[Documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options)

Answer (score 3):

It can be done with two ways like:

1 - Use $state

```
app.controller("fruitsCtrl", function ($scope, $state) {
    //goto vegetables page with params
    $state.go('vegetables', {name:"carrot"});
    // or other possibility
    $state.transitionTo('vegetables', {name:"carrot"});
});
```

2 - Use ui-sref

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a ui-sref="fruits({name: 'mango'})">Fruits</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="vegetables({name: 'potato'})">Vegetables</a></li>     
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Supposed Routes:

```
$stateProvider
                .state('fruits', {
                    url:"/fruits/:name",
                    templateUrl: "views/fruits.html",
                    controller: "fruitsCtrl"
                })
                .state('vegetables', {
                    url:"/vegetables/:name",
                    templateUrl: "views/vegetables.html",
                    controller: "vegetablesCtrl"
                });
```

Happy Helping!

Answer (score 2):

It would be simply like below.

```
$stateProvider.state('contacts', {
   url: '/:path',
   templateUrl: function ($stateParams){
     return '/Templates?path=' + $stateParams.path;
   }
 })
```

Convenience method for transitioning to a new state, `$state.go` which which internally calls `$state.transitionTo`. I'd preferred to use `$state.go` instead of `$scope.transitionTo`

```
$state.go("teststate",{ path: 'Test.TestState' });
```